# page_load called when calling webmethod using JQuery ajax

Tags: asp.net, web-services, jquery

I'm trying to call a webmethod inside a aspx page but only the page load event loads.

The webmethod:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function Test() As String
    Return "hello"
End Function
```

The ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../Custom/Policy.aspx/Test",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (data) { alert(data);},
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        console.log(request.responseText);
    }
});
```

The funny thing is I managed to make it work in the past and even looked at the code but still I can't make it work and now I gave up....

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the console to see if there are errors. This looks fine to me. Where is the ajax function called exactly?

Comment: from chrome\firefox console while i'm in a page in my web-app, trying to activate the webmethod

Comment: so what can you see in the console? Is the response text printed to the console? What status code do you see for the request

Comment: 200 - OK
And I get in return the whole aspx page after page_load function finishes.

Comment: add these arguments to your ajax call:

contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",

AFAIK the return type for calling a WebMethod MUST be "json".

Comment: I had those and I removed them....
Nevertheless I added them again and still it doesn't work.

Comment: can you also add the following param:    
data: {},

Comment: already did.
not working.

Comment: I managed to make it work:

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../Custom/default.aspx/Test",
    data : "{ routeType : \"dasdas\" }",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) { alert(data);},
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        console.log(request.responseText);
    }
});

The problem was I pass to data a native JSON object.
Once I passed this object as String it started to work!


Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was I pass to data a native JSON object. Once I passed this object as String it started to work!